# Mongoose find and return only a part of the document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My object:

```
[
    {
      "_id": "568ad3db59b494d4284ac191",
      "name": "Test",
      "groups": [
        {
          "number": "1",
          "name": "GroupTest",
          "_id": "568ad3db59b494d4284ac19b",
          "orders": [
            {
              "date": "2016-03-06T13:07:40.990Z",
              "_id": "56dc2b9c1d47772806e4f0f4",
              "readings": [
                {
                  "readingid": "568ad3db59b494d4284ac1a5",
                  "_id": "56dc2b9c1d47772806e4f0fc"
                },
                {
                  "readingid": "568ad3db59b494d4284ac1a4",
                  "_id": "56dc2b9c1d47772806e4f0fb"
                },
                {
                  "readingid": "568ad3db59b494d4284ac1a3",
                  "_id": "56dc2b9c1d47772806e4f0fa"
                },
                {
                  "readingid": "568ad3db59b494d4284ac1a2",
                  "_id": "56dc2b9c1d47772806e4f0f9"
                },
                {
                  "readingid": "56d48ae1a0f6e04413fc8b3e",
                  "_id": "56dc2b9c1d47772806e4f0f8"
                },
                {
                  "readingid": "56d48ae1a0f6e04413fc8b3f",
                  "_id": "56dc2b9c1d47772806e4f0f7"
                },
                {
                  "readingid": "568ad3db59b494d4284ac1a1",
                  "_id": "56dc2b9c1d47772806e4f0f6"
                },
                {
                  "readingid": "568ad3db59b494d4284ac1a0",
                  "_id": "56dc2b9c1d47772806e4f0f5"
                }
              ]
            },
            {....}
          ]
        },
        {....}
      ]
    },
    {.....}
]
```

I need to finde the order with the _id: "56dc2b9c1d47772806e4f0f4" in the group with the _id: "568ad3db59b494d4284ac19b" inside the client object with _id:"568ad3db59b494d4284ac191" and I only want to get that order subobject, not the whole client object.

I tried something like:

```
Client.find(
{_id: "568ad3db59b494d4284ac191", groups._id: "568ad3db59b494d4284ac19b", groups.orders._id:"56dc2b9c1d47772806e4f0f4"},
{groups.orders:{$elemMatch:{_id: "56dc2b9c1d47772806e4f0f4"}}})
```

Antoher attempt without success:

```
Client.find(
{_id: req.company, groups:ObjectId(req.params.groupId)},
{"groups.orders":{$elemMatch:{_id: ObjectId(req.params.orderId)}}}, function(e,company){
    if(!e) {
      console.log(company);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

mongo is a "document-oriented" database, so all the normal operations and queries it provides return "documents" and not "parts of documents", so with the normal query methods there is no way to get just a subobject.

You can use the mongo aggregation framework to achieve what you want (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/), using two `$unwind`: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/ .
This will produce a document for each `order` and then use `$match` to filter out the ones you need.

But probably it might be better to rethink your data model. If you really need to query and retrieve orders only, without getting the whole client object, it might be better to store the orders in their own collection and use references to groups and clients.